# Setting an observable on a 5 second timer RXJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, rx-android

I'm using RXJava 2 to perform an operation. I would like the operation to happen every 5 seconds. However after introducing the `interval` method it changes my function and breaks my `.subscribe(DisponsableObserver<Boolean>)`

```
mObserver = getObserver();              //return DisponsableObserver<Boolean>
observable = getSolultionObservable();  //return Observer<Boolean>

observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) 
            .subscribe(mSolutionObserver); //Now Produces Cannot Resolve Method error
```

How can I succesfully run my observable on a timer and return a boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `flatMap` operator for converting the items (`long`) emitted by the `interval` every 5 seconds, into your `Observable`

```
Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) 
    .flatMap(long -> observable)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(mSolutionObserver);
```

**EDIT**:
without lambda expression:

```
Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) 
    .flatMap(new Function<Long, ObservableSource<Boolean>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<Boolean> apply(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    return observable;
                }
            })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(mSolutionObserver);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `->` operator. Could you explain to me what you are doing with the `.flatmap()` line? I'm still not able to subscribe the mSolutionObserver. Thank you! I am new to RXjava

Comment: I edit the answer, adding the implementation without `->` operator, and I tried to explain what I did with `flatMap` operator. Keep in mind that if you are new with `RxJava` it will take a while for grasping its logic.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure out what to do before I came back. My solution looked exactly like yours. RXJava has been a bit difficult but I'm getting better :)